# Pinch Gesture for Function Other than Zooming- Unity

Tags: unity, raycasting, multitouch

I'm working on a game in which I want to pinch outwards on a character, which causes the character to split into 2 smaller copies of itself.

The method I'm thinking about using is to have the "pinch out" gesture destroy the game object and simultaneously create two instances of the smaller game object, and have them follow the fingers that pinch out. The action would also be reversible with the "pinch in" function.

My idea would be to do a raycast to detect the two-finger touch on the object (would I need a collider for that?), then use the beginning and ending touch points to determine if it is pinching out or in.

The problem is I am brand new to Unity and C# and have no idea how to write all of this. All of the tutorials for multi-touch gestures have to do with camera zoom, which is not what I am going for.

Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track with my logic and provide some guidance on writing the code?

Comment: Should a single finger touch/drag do anything in your game? Designing these two gestures together can help keep the interaction between them smooth, if so.

Comment: Yes, a single finger swiping gesture will have the character follow the finger up and down only.